# Tag overlap: Oracle APEX and Apex VisualForce

Tags: support, stack-overflow, retag-request

Hello.

It looks like two products overlap: Apex Visual force and Oracle Application Express (APEX).

The following questions both have the same tag [apex](/questions/tagged/apex):

- [Oracle APEX form based on multiple tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439844/oracle-apex-form-based-on-multiple-tables)
- [Get referrer in Apex Visualforce](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4462372/get-referrer-in-apex-visualforce)

Comment: Agreed. I've edited the **oracle** tag wiki accordingly.

Comment: Should I change `apex` tags to `oracle-apex` when I see it, then?

Comment: @Justing: I think this would be useful.

Comment: current the TAG APEX is still ambiguous.  I see now ONE new question with APEX-CODE for its tag. Seems an improvement but it feels lonely. is someone going to switcheroo?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not a subject expert, but as far as tags go, it sounds like they should be disambiguated into something like [apex-visualforce](/questions/tagged/apex-visualforce) (there is already [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce) which should also be removed), and [oracle-apex](/questions/tagged/oracle-apex).

Comment: I had the same idea about tag names.

Comment: Apex-code is currently being used in ONE question.  Should probably use that tag, as it's closer to the actual name used by the vendor (Apex-code).

Answer (score 1):

For the questions related to the following two products of http://www.salesforce.com:

- [Apex Code](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Apex) – a strongly-typed programming language that executes on the Force.com platform.
- [Visualforce](http://wiki.developerforce.com/index.php/Visualforce) – a complete component-based framework for building and deploying custom user interfaces on Force.com.

I'm suggesting the two appropriate tags:

- [apex-code](/questions/tagged/apex-code)
- [visualforce](/questions/tagged/visualforce)

The former is not used. The latter is already used by a number of questions.

I'm also suggesting to get rid of [apex](/questions/tagged/apex) completely, and already explained it here ["Banned tags facility"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/79265/147036).

As there's already [salesforce](/questions/tagged/salesforce), I feel that it's a good idea to use it in combination with one of the above or either tags.

This way the products of two companies obviously don't overlap.