# Banned tags facility

Tags: feature-request, support, tags

Is there a facility, either planned or available, to prevent some ambiguous and/or overlapping tags from being used. See, for example, this discussion [Tag overlap: Oracle APEX and APEX VisualForce](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/73007/147036).

I think that [apex](/questions/tagged/apex) could be safely banned, because, for instance, the question [Oracle APEX: popup menu](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4992670/298282) before editing had [apex](/questions/tagged/apex), while the better fit would be to have [oracle-apex](/questions/tagged/oracle-apex) on it, and you could understand neither from initial tags nor from the title what this question is about unitl you follow it and read the question.

[apex](/questions/tagged/apex) neither adds anyting useful to the question, nor does it remove the ambiguity. I would get rid of it and retag existing questions having [apex](/questions/tagged/apex) to have [oracle-apex](/questions/tagged/oracle-apex).

Comment: I support this.

Comment: This is a possible duplicate of [Implement a Tag Black List](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/implement-a-tag-black-list)

Answer (score 1):

This is why we have [tag synonyms](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/oracle-apex/synonyms).

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms).

Comment: Nope, tag synonyms are not useful in such case, as "apex" could refer to several unrelated products, and you couldn't safely retag "apex" to, for instance, "oracle-apex".